# Why there's no hibernate/sleep option for Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server

I am using Windows Server 2008 R2 Box for my development purpose. I could not see any hibernate/sleep option in the shutdown options. What could be the reason to hide these options for a server machine?

Comment: Maybe because there's no use for those options on a server? Why would a server ever need to hibernate and not shut down or restart?

Comment: yea I agree. hibernation/sleep isn't really suitable for a server environment. I just wanted to make sure if it's the only reason.

Comment: Not all servers are required 24/7.  If your servers are running LOB operations for a single time zone then it makes sense to have them reduce power usage when not required.  Many companies have around 40 working hours in a week and there are 168 hours in a week.

Comment: True. But some people arrive early (before 7AM), some leave late (say 8 PM). Some work on the servers from home (e.g. me, usually 8 to 10 hours per weekend). So a **Server** often needs to be on for far more than the 40 hours.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you installed Hype-v role? If yes, then Windows disables the Sleep and Hibernate options. You will need to make the Hyper-V service start on Demand for Sleep and Hibernate options to be re-enabled.

Refer to this [blog post](http://arjunachith.blogspot.com/2010/06/enable-hibernate-and-sleep-with-hyper-v_05.html?cf03B90407=83A0A8167!MTA1MDQ0OTYwOmNvcnByYWRpdXNzc286bTcdUX3Yw5rLCDVacXvccA==) for details.